# how to click event in css

Tags: php, html, css

This works:

```css
.rightone ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
.rightone ul li {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    float:right;
}
.rightone li ul {
    display: none;
}
.rightone ul li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 30px 5px 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
    white-space: nowrap;

}
.rightone ul li li {
    background-color: black;
    border-radius:5px;
    padding: 2%;
}
.rightone ul li a:hover {
    color:#0ef2c4;
}
.rightone li:active ul {
    display: block; 
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
}
.rightone li:hover li {
    float: none;
}
.rightone li:hover a {
    color:#0ef2c4;
}
.rightone li:hover li a:hover {
    color:white;
}
.arrow-down {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 8px solid transparent;
    border-right: 8px solid transparent;
    border-top: 8px solid #0ef2c4;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

But it work only when i hold... but i need, if i single click show that pop-up again click that arrow  it will hide..

[My output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62IKo.png)

I want to move that pop up left side also..

I want like this

https://jsfiddle.net/z4fej7gm/
But i dont know how apply to my project

Please anyone help me.. Thanks in advance

Comment: you can use JQuery for this if you're familiar with that

Comment: No.. Im not familiar... please help

Comment: `<script>
$(".arrow").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass(".expanded");
}); 
</script>`
Basically what this means, is when you click the arrow element, you toggle the CSS Class `.expanded` (switch this out with your own class). This way you can show or hide elements by clicking.

Comment: For the above to work, you will need to attach a JQuery library to your page, either locally or via a CDN such as this one hosted by google `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: I want like this https://jsfiddle.net/z4fej7gm/          But i dont know how apply to my project

Answer (score 1):

Css doesn't support click events